# How do I parse a very long String in xml?

Tags: android, xml

I have a Parser class.  It seems to be returning only a certain amount of characters and not the entire string.
It stops at the "&" sybmol for all my Strings

e.g
http://video.site.com/vidfasfasfdasdfjkdhfhafjhajsdkdhfd.mp4?Epoch=1231736487124&Policy=ew0KIlN0YXRlbWVudCI6W3sNCiJSZXNvdXJjZS

it will return http://video.site.com/vidfasfasfdasdfjkdhfhafjhajsdkdhfd.mp4?Epoch=123173648712  only

What modification can I make so it returns the entire string?

```
public class Parser extends Activity {

//No generics
private List<Video> myVideos;
private Document dom;
private String TAG = "Parser";

/*
 * Constructor
 */
public Parser(){
    //create a list to hold the video objects
    myVideos = new ArrayList<Video>();
}

/*
 * parse xml file 
 * @param File path
 */
void parseXmlFile(String path){
    //get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    try {

        //Using factory get an instance of document builder
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
        dom = db.parse(path);


    }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    }catch(SAXException se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/*
 * 
 */
public void runParser(String path){
     parseXmlFile(path);
     parseDocument();
     printData();
}


/*
 * parse DOM object
 * Pass each element to getVideo
 */
void parseDocument(){
    //get the root elememt
    Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

    //get a nodelist of <video> elements

    NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("item");
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++) {   
            //get the video element
            Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);   
            //get the video object
            Video e = getVideo(el);

            //add it to list
            myVideos.add(e);
        }
    }
}


/*
 * I take an Video element and read the values in, create
 * an Video object and return it
 * @param Video
 * @return
 */
private Video getVideo(Element videoEle){

    //for each <Video> element get text or int values of 
    //StreamUrl , thumbNail, title , episode, description etc


    //Topmost Node elements e.g  playlist 
    Node parentNode = getParentNode(videoEle);
    Element parentElement = (Element)parentNode;


    //Node with item Element
    String streamUrl = getTextValue(videoEle,"streamUrl");
    String thumbNail = getTextValue(videoEle,"thumbnail");
    String title = getTextValue(videoEle,"title");
    String episode = getTextValue(videoEle,"episode");
    String descr = getTextValue(videoEle,"description");


    //Get element Attribute
    String playListName = parentElement.getAttribute("name");
    String linkXMLURL = videoEle.getAttribute("linkXMLURL");

    //Create a new Video object with the value read from the xml nodes
    Video e = new Video(playListName,linkXMLURL,streamUrl,thumbNail,title,episode,descr);

    return e;
}


/*
 * Take a xml element and the tag name
 * look for the tag and get the text content  
 * @param ele
 * @param tagName
 * @return String
 */
private String getTextValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
    String textVal = null;
    NodeList nl = ele.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        Element el = (Element)nl.item(0);
        textVal = el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
    }

    return textVal;
}


/*
 * Calls getTextValue
 * @param ele
 * @param tagName
 * @return int
 */
private int getIntValue(Element ele, String tagName) {
    //in production application you would catch the exception
    return Integer.parseInt(getTextValue(ele,tagName));
}


/*
 * @param ele
 * @return Node
 */
private Node getParentNode(Element ele){    
    Node parentNode = ele.getParentNode();
    return parentNode;

}

public List<Video> getList(){
    return myVideos;
}

public int getCount(){
    return myVideos.size();
}

/*
 * Iterate through the list and print the 
 * content to console
 */
void printData(){       
    System.out.println("No of Videos'" + myVideos.size() + "'.");

    Iterator<Video> it = myVideos.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        //System.out.println(it.next().toString());
        Log.i(TAG, it.next().printURL());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){ 


}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I normalized the Element it work perfectly fine.

**Element.normalize( )**
The normalize method normalizes all subtree Text nodes, i.e., it combines two or more adjacent ones into a single one. In 'normal' form, text nodes can only be separated by markup such as tags, comments, processing instructions, CDATA sections and entity references. This form is useful for operations requiring a particular document structure, and ensures that the DOM view of the document remains the same when saved and reloaded.

```
void parseDocument(){
//get the root elememt
Element docEle = dom.getDocumentElement();

docEle.normalize();

//get a nodelist of <video> elements

NodeList nl = docEle.getElementsByTagName("item");
if(nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength();i++) {   
        //get the video element
        Element el = (Element)nl.item(i);   
        //get the video object
        Video e = getVideo(el);

        //add it to list
        myVideos.add(e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ampersand is a special character in XML. You need to use `&amp;` in your source XML instead.

You can find a list of XML special characters [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

Comment: I'm unable to modify the source file. How do instruct my parser to ignore he special character?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a SAX parser instead.

Comment: Your source file is not XML, so don't try to parse it with an XML parser. You either need to change your system so it transmits proper well-formed XML, or you need to define your own non-XML language and write your own tools to process it. I know which route I would choose.

Comment: Tried Sax parser experiencing the same issue.

Comment: The source file is an xml, the links I provided above are just an example of issue. I tried it with a well form xml local to my computer and I am still experiencing the same issue.